# Specified cast is not valid.. how to resolve this

Tags: c#

I have the below function

```
public object Convert(object value)
 {
    string retVal = string.Empty;
    int oneMillion = 1000000;
    retVal = ((double)value / oneMillion).ToString("###,###,###.###");
    return retVal;
 }
```

I am invoking like

```
var result  = Convert(107284403940);
```

Error: **"Specified cast is not valid."**

how to fix...

Note:~ the object value can be double, decimal, float, integer(32 and 64)..anything

Is it possible to do the typecasting at runtime?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Use `Convert.ToDouble(value)` rather than `(double)value`.  It takes an `object` and supports all of the types you asked for! :)

Also, your method is always returning a `string` in the code above; I'd recommend having the method indicate so, and give it a more obvious name (`public string FormatLargeNumber(object value)`)

Comment: This will **overflow for decimal** as OP is saying value can be decimal.

Comment: I don't think so: `double.MaxValue` is 1.7976931E+308, `decimal.MaxValue` is 7.9228E+24.  Do you have a source?

Comment: [Conversions from Decimal to Single or Double are narrowing conversions that might lose precision but not information about the magnitude of the converted value.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k2e8atx(v=VS.71).aspx) because Decimal is **128** bit number where as double is **64** bits long

Comment: Yes, it might lose precision, but it will not overflow.  Your solution will not work because it IS possible for it to overflow. Sorry!

Comment: agreed. Undid my downvote, I was only thinking about the width of the number not magnitude or range.

Answer (score 5):

If you are expecting `double, decimal, float, integer` why not use the one which accomodates all namely **decimal** (128 bits are enough for most numbers you are looking at).

instead of `(double)value` use `decimal.Parse(value.ToString())` or `Convert.ToDecimal(value)`

Comment: This may *overflow for double* as OP is saying value can be double. [128 bits of precision does not mean decimal can store larger values ;)]

Comment: Yes, **really** large or small decimal values will overflow this solution. Would have deleted my answer, but keeping it as a **warning sign**

Comment: Convert.ToDecimal(value) - this is workded for me.... thanks