# How would I return an object or multiple values from PowerShell to executing C# code

Tags: c#, powershell

Some C# code executes a powershell script with arguments. I want to get a returncode and a string back from Powershell to know, if everything was ok inside the Powershell script.

What is the right way to do that - in both Powershell and C#

#### Powershell

```
# Powershell script
# --- Do stuff here ---
# Return an int and a string - how?
# In c# I would do something like this, if this was a method:

# class ReturnInfo
# {
#    public int ReturnCode;
#    public string ReturnText;
# }

# return new ReturnInfo(){ReturnCode =1, ReturnText = "whatever"};
```

#### C#

```
void RunPowershellScript(string scriptFile, List<string> parameters)
    {
        
        RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();

        using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration))
        {
            runspace.Open();
            RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);
            Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
            Command scriptCommand = new Command(scriptFile);
            Collection<CommandParameter> commandParameters = new Collection<CommandParameter>();
            foreach (string scriptParameter in parameters)
            {
                CommandParameter commandParm = new CommandParameter(null, scriptParameter);
                commandParameters.Add(commandParm);
                scriptCommand.Parameters.Add(commandParm);
            }
            pipeline.Commands.Add(scriptCommand);
            Collection<PSObject> psObjects;
            psObjects = pipeline.Invoke();

            //What to do here?
            //ReturnInfo returnInfo = pipeline.DoMagic();

        }
    }

  class ReturnInfo
  {
      public int ReturnCode;
      public string ReturnText;
  }
```

I have managed to do this is some hacky ways by using Write-Output and relying on conventions like "last two psObjects are the values I am looking for", but it would break very easily.

Comment: As you've prepared for, the `Invoke` returns **An array of objects that contain the output of the pipeline. If the pipeline has no output, an emptycollection is returned.** so I am uncertain as to what you expect... are you asking how to tweak your powershell  to return the values you expect?

Comment: Joshua Drake>> I have added a bit of c# to the powershell script comments, I hope that makes it clearer, what I want. :)

Comment: Would something like [return multiple values from Poweshell function](http://martinzugec.blogspot.com/2009/08/how-to-return-multiple-values-from.html) be any help?

Comment: Joshua Drake>> It would! Now I just need to figure out the other half - how to read that from C# code.

Comment: You should be able to examin `psObjects` in the debugger and see if you have some generic dictionary object, or something with a specific structure and work off that.

Comment: any final solution with full source code?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In your powershell script you can build an Hashtable based on your necessity:

```
[hashtable]$Return = @{} 
$Return.ReturnCode = [int]1 
$Return.ReturnString = [string]"All Done!" 
Return $Return
```

In C# code handle the Psobject in this way

```
 ReturnInfo ri = new ReturnInfo();
 foreach (PSObject p in psObjects)
 {
   Hashtable ht = p.ImmediateBaseObject as Hashtable;
   ri.ReturnCode = (int)ht["ReturnCode"];
   ri.ReturnText = (string)ht["ReturnString"];
 } 

//Do what you want with ri object.
```

If you want to use a PsCustomobject as in Keith Hill comment in powershell v2.0:

powershell script:

```
$return = new-object psobject -property @{ReturnCode=1;ReturnString="all done"}
$return
```

c# code:

```
ReturnInfo ri = new ReturnInfo();
foreach (PSObject p in psObjects)
   {
     ri.ReturnCode = (int)p.Properties["ReturnCode"].Value;
     ri.ReturnText = (string)p.Properties["ReturnString"].Value;
   }
```

Comment: this way you can set fields of any class not only hashtable

Comment: @vittore Yes, in fact on V3 this should be even easier using a pscustomobject `$return = new-object psobject -property @{ReturnCode=1;Result="all done"}` and C# 4's dynamic keyword.  Ya know, since V3 is now DLR based.

Comment: If the PowerShell script for instance calls Write-Host, the ImmediateBaseObject is null. Pattern matching should be used in C#. Example: if (p.ImmediateBaseObject is Hashtable ht) { ... }

Answer (score 7):

[CB.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10108756/3850012) worked great for me with a minor change. I did not see this posted anywhere (in regards to C# and PowerShell) so I wanted to post it.

In my PowerShell script I created created a Hashtable, stored 2 values in it (a Boolean and an Int) and then converted that into a PSObject:

```
$Obj = @{}

if($RoundedResults -ilt $Threshold)
{
    $Obj.bool = $true
    $Obj.value = $RoundedResults
}
else
{
    $Obj.bool = $false
    $Obj.value = $RoundedResults
}

$ResultObj = (New-Object PSObject -Property $Obj)

return $ResultObj
```

And then in  my C# code I did the same thing that CB. did but I had to use `Convert.ToString` in order to successfully get the values back:

```
ReturnInfo ri = new ReturnInfo();
foreach (PSObject p in psObjects)
   {
     ri.ReturnCode = Convert.ToBoolean(p.Properties["ReturnCode"].Value;)
     ri.ReturnText = Convert.ToString(p.Properties["ReturnString"].Value;)
   }
```

I found the answer to this via the following StackOverflow post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5577500

Where Kieren Johnstone says:

> Use Convert.ToDouble(value) rather than (double)value. It takes an
>   object and supports all of the types you asked for! :)

Answer (score 1):

Wow, good question! I'll take a shot off the top of my head...

You could design a class in C# that represents the structure you want to use to pass data between the two. In the PS script, you could use an XmlWriter to craft an XML response and use `Write-output` to spit out the XML string.

On the C# side, capture the standard out response, deserialize the XML into your new response class, and then process the result. Note that you can't write anything out to stdout other than your XML response, or else you won't be able to deserialze into the class.

Answer (score 0):

For PowerShell v3.0 and newer it is even simpler:

```
$myObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
    Name     = 'Kevin'
    Language = 'PowerShell'
    State    = 'Texas'
}
$myObject.Name = 'Mark'
return $myObject
```