# How to take the data returned from using windows tools (EXE files)?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, output, console-application

[This sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee706580%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) shows how to add a script to the pipeline of a PowerShell object and how to run the script asynchronously. Events are used to handle the output of the script.

But when I change the content of the script from

```
powershell.AddScript("1..10 | foreach {$_ ; start-sleep -milli 500}");
```

to

```
powershell.AddScript("qwinsta");
```

or to

```
powershell.AddScript("$t = qwinsta");
powershell.AddScript("echo $t");
```

Result always show null. 
How to take the data returned by running the EXE?

Edit: Code added (Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V is to hard ;) )

```
namespace Microsoft.Samples.PowerShell.Runspaces
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Management.Automation;
    using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
    using PowerShell = System.Management.Automation.PowerShell;

    /// <summary>
    /// This class contains the Main entry point for this host application.
    /// </summary>
    internal class Runspace09
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// This sample shows how to use a PowerShell object to run a 
        /// script that generates the numbers from 1 to 10 with delays
        /// between each number. The pipeline of the PowerShell object 
        /// is run asynchronously and events are used to handle the output.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args">The parameter is not used.</param>
        /// <remarks>
        /// This sample demonstrates the following:
        /// 1. Creating a PowerShell object.
        /// 2. Adding a script to the pipeline of the PowerShell object.
        /// 3. Using the BeginInvoke method to run the pipeline asynchronously.
        /// 4. Using the events of the PowerShell object to process the 
        ///    output of the script.
        /// 5. Using the PowerShell.Stop() method to interrupt the invocation of 
        ///    the pipeline.
        /// </remarks>
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Print the numbers from 1 to 10. Hit any key to halt processing\n");

            using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                // Add a script to the PowerShell object. The script generates the 
                // numbers from 1 to 10 in half second intervals.
                powershell.AddScript("$t = qwinsta; echo $t");

                // Add the event handlers.  If we did not care about hooking the DataAdded
                // event, we would let BeginInvoke create the output stream for us.
                PSDataCollection<PSObject> output = new PSDataCollection<PSObject>();
                output.DataAdded += new EventHandler<DataAddedEventArgs>(Output_DataAdded);
                powershell.InvocationStateChanged += new EventHandler<PSInvocationStateChangedEventArgs>(Powershell_InvocationStateChanged);

                // Invoke the pipeline asynchronously.
                IAsyncResult asyncResult = powershell.BeginInvoke<PSObject, PSObject>(null, output);

                // Wait for things to happen. If the user hits a key before the
                // script has completed, then call the PowerShell Stop() method
                // to halt processing.
                Console.ReadKey();
                if (powershell.InvocationStateInfo.State != PSInvocationState.Completed)
                {
                    // Stop the invocation of the pipeline.
                    Console.WriteLine("\nStopping the pipeline!\n");
                    powershell.Stop();

                    // Wait for the Windows PowerShell state change messages to be displayed.
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                    Console.WriteLine("\nPress a key to exit");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The output data added event handler. This event is called when
        /// data is added to the output pipe. It reads the data that is 
        /// available and displays it on the console.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The output pipe this event is associated with.</param>
        /// <param name="e">Parameter is not used.</param>
        private static void Output_DataAdded(object sender, DataAddedEventArgs e)
        {
            PSDataCollection<PSObject> myp = (PSDataCollection<PSObject>)sender;

            Collection<PSObject> results = myp.ReadAll();
            foreach (PSObject result in results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This event handler is called when the pipeline state is changed.
        /// If the state change is to Completed, the handler issues a message
        /// asking the user to exit the program.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">This parameter is not used.</param>
        /// <param name="e">The PowerShell state information.</param>
        private static void Powershell_InvocationStateChanged(object sender, PSInvocationStateChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("PowerShell object state changed: state: {0}\n", e.InvocationStateInfo.State);
            if (e.InvocationStateInfo.State == PSInvocationState.Completed)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Processing completed, press a key to exit!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unclear what you're asking.  Possible duplicate of [this question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106217/how-would-i-return-an-object-or-multiple-values-from-powershell-to-executing-c-s?rq=1) also.  Link to MSDN sample code isn't sufficient to know what _your_ code is doing.

Comment: I use exactly the same code as the link (ofc one change in line with AddScript). Description of what the code is doing is at top of my question and in the attached link. What is unclear? :(

Comment: Now you have all in one place. :) Also, this is not duplicate (They are working with commands)

Answer (score 0):

Delimit commands within the script using a semicolon as the sample suggests.  Note that you've got two separate processes in the following:

```
powershell.AddScript("$t = qwinsta");
powershell.AddScript("echo $t");
```

But as soon as you add *one* script instead:

```
powershell.AddScript("$t = qwinsta; echo $t");
```

Then you're back in business.

Edit: According to your comments there's additional code of yours that you haven't provided.  Until that shows up in the question there's not much anyone can know for certain.  Please post *your* code.

Comment: Still null in returned object.

Comment: Object?  What object?  You may need to supply more of your code.

Comment: Check link to msdn. Function: Output_DataAdded, Line: Console.WriteLine(result.ToString()); result is null.