# Gridview if condition Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using the the below code to show the image in gridview using some condition. It returns the error "Specified cast is not valid.". I can't Understand this error.

```
<asp:Image ID="img_lock" runat="server" ImageAlign="AbsMiddle" ImageUrl='<%#  ((double)Eval("FLD_LOCK_MONTH") < 3) ? "~/images/ico_lock.png" : "~/images/ico_unlock.png"%>' />
```

Comment: what type is FLD_LOCK_MONTH?

Answer (score 3):

Use `Convert.ToDouble(value)` rather than `(double)value`. It takes an object and supports all of the types you asked for!

Also check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577484/specified-cast-is-not-valid-how-to-resolve-this).

Comment: Check the datatype for "FLD_LOCK_MONTH".

Comment: its from a query not a column name

Comment: what data and what datatype you are using for "FLD_LOCK_MONTH"?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with checking conditions inside of url attribute, why can't you check the condition before the tag creation ?