# How to add two column value in one final amount?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I have datatable in c#, I want to add two column value in one, Add means `2+2 =4` like that. please help me this  my below code not working

```
for (int i = 0; i < dtOrdersDetail.Rows.Count; i++)
{
  DataRow dtItemRow = dtOrderReceipt.NewRow();
  dtItemRow["FinalAmount"] = dtOrdersDetail.Rows[i]["ComboAmount"] + dtOrdersDetail.Rows[i]["TotalPrice"];
}
```

Comment: how not working? getting blank lines? or only totals?

Comment: try using cast (for exemple, `dtItemRow["FinalAmount"] = (int)dtOrdersDetail.Rows[i]["ComboAmount"] + (int)dtOrdersDetail.Rows[i]["TotalPrice"];`

Where (int) should be the correct datatype...

Comment: @carlosfcmendes   Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: As i said, you should put de correct datatype... (int) it was just a sample... Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577484

Answer (score 1):

In this Case you have to correct the code in two place.

1. Cast the source data table Columns.

   `dtItemRow["FinalAmount"] = Convert.ToInt32(dtOrdersDetail.Rows[i]["ComboAmount"]) + Convert.ToInt32(dtOrdersDetail.Rows[i]["TotalPrice"]);`
2. Add the row in data table.

   `dtOrderReceipt.Rows.Add(dtItemRow);`

So **in summary** your code look likes as below

```
 for (int i = 0; i < dtOrdersDetail.Rows.Count; i++)
  {
      DataRow dtItemRow = dtOrderReceipt.NewRow();
      dtItemRow["FinalAmount"] = Convert.ToInt32(dtOrdersDetail.Rows[i]["ComboAmount"]) + Convert.ToInt32(dtOrdersDetail.Rows[i]["TotalPrice"]);
      dtOrderReceipt.Rows.Add(dtItemRow);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

@john, look at the below logic

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("TotalPrice", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("ComboAmount", typeof(int));

// Here we add five DataRows.
table.Rows.Add(10,10);
table.Rows.Add(20,20);
table.Rows.Add(30,20);

DataTable dtOrderReceipt = new DataTable(); 
dtOrderReceipt.Columns.Add("FinalAmount", typeof(int));

for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataRow dtItemRow = dtOrderReceipt.NewRow();
    dtOrderReceipt.Rows.InsertAt(dtItemRow, i);
    dtItemRow["FinalAmount"] = (int)table.Rows[i]["ComboAmount"] + (int)table.Rows[i]["TotalPrice"];
}
```

I think after create a newrow you forgot to Inject it on your Datatable. i.e.

```
 DataRow dtItemRow = dtOrderReceipt.NewRow();
 dtOrderReceipt.Rows.InsertAt(dtItemRow, i);
```

Let me know is that logic works for you?